# Powershell Replace Column data with new output of a command

Tags: powershell, csv

I think I have a basic PowerShell question that most of you guys know how to answer.

When I export a list from lets say my AD, this is a csv list with the following headers:

CsDNSHostName, WindowsVersion, Any (In that case any is something that may change due to User action)

So now I have my CSV which I have exported I then want to keep this csv up to date.
In my environment the "ANY" header may change often and also there may come new computers to the list and Old ones disappear...

So now I need a way to keep my csv updated without having to create multiple csv files, also I don't want duplicate entries inside the csv so it.

Here is the code I think might be used, but I'm sure I'm wrong because my knowledge is to low to get this running properly, getting the Data is easy but making it Updatable, not...

```
#Runs once and afterwards I use the csv that was created as Base for all other operations
Get-ADComputer -Filter * | export-csv "c:\mycsv.csv"

$impc = import-csv "c:\mycsv.csv"

$impc | Select CsName,@{Name="WindowsVersion";Expression={

       $data = invoke-command -computername $_.ComputerName -scriptblock {get-computerinfo}
       $data.WindowsVersion

 }},@{Name="ANY";Expression={

       $data = invoke-command -computername $_.ComputerName -scriptblock {get-computerinfo}
       $data.ANY

 }} | Export-CSV "C:\mycsv.csv"
```

Comment: Just add `-Force` to your `Export-Csv` command (also `-NoTypeInformation`).

Comment: I dont think that my "solution" works properly...
I think I need to use this https://itpro.outsidesys.com/2017/10/21/powershell-change-values-in-csv-data/ in combination with foreach and compare the rows (using the computername as uniqe identifier)

Answer (score 1):

To not multiple times run the Invoke-Command with Get-ComputerInfo
I'd try something like this:

```
$impc = Get-ADComputer -Filter * | ForEach {
    $data = invoke-command -computername $_.ComputerName -scriptblock {get-computerinfo}
    [PsCustomObject]@{
        CsName         = $_.CsName
        WindowsVersion = $data.WindowsVersion
        ANY            = $data.ANY
    }
}
$impc | Export-CSV "C:\mycsv.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Will this change the current Lines and add new ones(In case a new PC gets added), while waiting for some anwsers here , I found out about this https://itpro.outsidesys.com/2017/10/21/powershell-change-values-in-csv-data/
Cant I use this in combination with foreach and then compare the Cloumns of every Line and say (If column "any" != $_.any(from get adcomputer) then $any = $_.any, else add new column timestamplastcheck

This way I could check each row (Needing an Uniqe identifier) and replace if something is different. If it is not I get the last checked date. Thats a concept that may work?

Comment: The script will build the $impc  object from scratch by iterating over Get-AdComputer output getting computerinfo once and stuff the data in properties you choose. If you export to a different name there is no problme simply trying. To sync with any prior data different steps are required.

Comment: Get-ComputerInfo | select WindowsVersion no longer works for 21h1 - it shows 2009 (same as 20h2)